# TableViewCell particular cell does not properly highlight

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

This is my main screen[image] when click on cell highlighted description goes to next view controller and cell is highlighted and when i am click on cell not highlighted thus cell not highlighted that's means only zero index cell highlighted no one other like one index second index how to highlight others.

I'm trying to add highlight cell in tableview like this:

[image]

But in my code only highlight the first cell means zero index

[image]

When click on second cell the second cell is not highlighted

[image]

How to highlight selected cell?

This is my function to highlight code:

```
func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool,animated: Bool){
    if commentView != nil{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
            self.commentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 235/256, green: 187/256, blue: 194/256, alpha: 1.0)
        }) { (completed) in
            if completed {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
                    self.commentView.backgroundColor = .clear
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove code under `setHighlighted` that set background color.
This is not the correct way to update, you can use `setSelected` inside `UITableVIewCell`

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: true)

    if selected {
        // set selected color
    } else {
        // set un-selected color
    }
}
```

OR following approach

Allow multiple row selection from storyboard OR via code

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

let selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView
```

OR

```
cell.multipleSelectionBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView
```

Comment: @RahulKaura You should share your view controller and UITableViewCell code. Validate you are calling `super. setHighlighted` in your  `setHighlighted` in `UITableViewCell` if its an override

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 10 Swift4**

Implement the below method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 235/256, green: 187/256, blue: 194/256, alpha: 1.0)
    }) { (completed) in
        if completed {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
                tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer should work. It highlights any cell that is clicked.